# Classpath incompatibility:Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am running my flutter app on release mode and I have errors showing incompatible versions of dependencies but the app builds fine nonetheless.

```
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.10/e80fe6ac3c3573a80305f5ec43f86b829e8ab53d/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
e: C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.5.0/857678d6b4ca7b28571ef7935c668bdb57e15027/annotation-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
 C:/Users/Bina/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.10/e80fe6ac3c3573a80305f5ec43f86b829e8ab53d/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
 Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
```

I have tries changing the dependencies but I still get the errors.